# Importing package in Typescript

Tags: import, typescript

How do I write a importing is equivalent to `import React, { Component } from 'react-native'`?

In typescript(es6 mode), it only accepts, has to split into two importings:

```
import * as React from 'react-native'
import { Component } from 'react-native'
```

How do I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In typescript(es6 mode), it only accepts, has to split into two importings:

You have to do it like that. And you should do it like that for Babel as well.

Otherwise you will end up with [tears](https://medium.com/@kentcdodds/misunderstanding-es6-modules-upgrading-babel-tears-and-a-solution-ad2d5ab93ce0#.rqwfwfetx).

This is because `React` is *not the default export* but it is synthetically made one by Babel. It emits a function that copies `export =` to `default` which is something that TypeScript refuses to do to prevent future troubles.

Comment: Note: This might change in the future https://github.com/nodejs/node-eps/blob/8e2ac8ffbe17c837ffa9546f9324727040d0ebce/002-es6-modules.md#es-consuming-commonjs if NodeJS provides native loading for ES6 syntax

Comment: in July, 2017 something changed?

Comment: @stackdave nope